# Visual Studio Code and MSVC++2017 (tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I am relatively new to Visual Studio Code.  I want to use VSC to create executables using C++ with the following compilers:

```
clang (on windows from cygwin)
gcc (on windows from cygwin)
msvc++2017 (native on windows, obviously)
```

As I was reading about VSC with C++ I thought that the gcc and clang (from cygwin) settings in tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json would prove the most difficult.  In fact, they were the easiest..once I got bash properly configured.  Now I am struggling with getting the C++ compiler from Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to work.

The only solution I have found uses a batch file that looks like this:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64     
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc
set linkerflags=/OUT:hello.exe
cl.exe %compilerflags% helloworld.cpp /link %linkerflags%
```

but I'm thinking that this is not correct or perhaps not optimal.  Why do I think this?  Because if this were the case, why would the VSC developers provide an includePath entry in the example c_cpp_properties.json file that contains the actual include paths to my MSVC++2017 compiler?  And then not rely on them...

So, I'm hoping that someone can show me example tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json entries and the shell configuration to use with the Microsoft C++ compiler.  Or better yet, if there are examples out there, please point me at them.  I've looked high and low and can't find them...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1839 is related and may help.